# Tilting a 3d object to face a camera and have it look like it's spinning on the y axis

Tags: 3d, scenekit, rotational-matrices

Like the question says I have a scene kit app I'm working on and at a certain point I move the camera under a list of objects and tilt it up to give a star wars type view of them. I then need to pull the objects up one at a time and face them at the camera. All of this is working however the last step is making them rotate so while facing the camera it looks like it's spinning on it's y axis.

I'm setting my camera's eularAngles.x to .75. I then do the same to the object i'm bringing to the foreground so it faces the camera. I cannot for the life of me figure the matrix math to make it spin correctly. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To make it spin you could do something like this:

```
    someNode.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: 1, z: 0, duration: 1)))
```

You could also use `SCNLookAtConstraint` to make it look at the camera.  [Here is the reference.](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnlookatconstraint)